# python os.utime doesn't update the access time

Tags: python

I'm trying to modify the access timestamp and modify timestamp of a remote file 
I'm using the following line:

```
os.utime(filePath, (1267533581,1267090862))
```

the modify timestamp get updated but the access timestamp doesn't

I have tried to use this on a local file on a local file and everything is working well 
I'm working on windows. the file system is NTFS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the last access time is disabled on your system. This could have been done for performance purposes. It's controlled by a registry setting. See:

http://www.pctools.com/guides/registry/detail/50