# Changing a directory time/date

Tags: c, linux, winapi

I tried `utime()` on both Windows (XP) and Linux. On Windows I get an `EACCES` error, on Linux I don't get any error (but the time is not changed). My `utime()` code is fine, because it works on files. I could not find if `utime()` is supposed to work on directories or not, but if not, how can I change the time and date?

I am looking for a solution that would ideally work for both Windows and Linux, but if not, I can always use some OS specific code.

[edit]
It seems that utime does indeed work on Linux, but it didn't appear to work for me because I was moving files in that directory, and that updated the time stamp to the current time.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363497/python-os-utime-doesnt-update-the-access-time

Comment: Unfortunately not really related, I can't update the timestamp at all (last accessed or modified).

Comment: Yes, but maybe the same registry key *and* another one are off?

Comment: The problem that guy had was with the access time, which can be disabled (to speed up stuff usually). But I can't changed the modified time stamp either. And it happens on Linux also. And it works on files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows you can use the [SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which also works for directories.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to try it, but Windows has been giving me a lot of trouble today. I had to use CreateFile in order to get a handle to that directory that I can use for SetFileTime. So I did this: src_dir=CreateFile(source,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,CREATE_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL); Well, I am getting an "Access is denied" error :/

Comment: The flag CREATE_ALWAYS is probably the problem. If the directory exists use OPEN_ALWAYS. Otherwise use CreateDirectory to create a directory. Additionally a handle used with SetFileTime has to be opened with the FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES right. GENERIC_READ does not imply this right.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to: src_dir=CreateFile(source,GENERIC_READ,FILE_SHARE_READ,NULL,OPEN_ALWAYS,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL); and still the same access violation :/ The reason why I am using GENERIC_READ is because I want to use the complementary function, GetFileTime(). What I am trying to do is copy directories, and I want to set the date of the newly created directory to the same date as the original one.

Comment: Oh, isn't Windows sweet? Buried deep in the msdn page for CreateFile, it mentions that if you want to open a directory you MUST set the flag FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS... Now I set it and it magically works! Thanks a lot for this SetFileTime function, it works as it should :) Now if only I could find how to do it on Linux :/